# For all prime numbers $P$ ($P > 2$), does positive rational solution $(x, y, z)$ exist for $P^x + P^y = P^z$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$\forall x,y,z \in {\mathbb Q}^+$, I want to prove that
$$P^x + P^y \neq P^z$$
always holds for all prime $P$ ($P > 2$).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot $P > 2$. Otherwise, this question is trivial for $P = 2$.

Comment: Well, there are no positive integral solutions for $P > 2$.  W.l.o.g $x \ge y$ so we can rewrite it $P^x(1 + P^{y - x}) = P^z$ but the LHS is clearly not a multiple of P but the RHS is.

Comment: @badjohn Does one have to cancel $P^x$ with part of $P^z$ before concluding left side not a multiple of $P$ in your argument? [this might be obvious...]

Comment: I have a mistype.  I said "wlog $x \ge y$ but continued as if $x \le y$.  The idea was to move the common factor of $P^x$ outside of the parentheses.  So, I have not changed the value of the LHS and hence don't need to change the value of the RHS.  
If $x = y$ then the value of the parentheses is 2 and hence not a multiple of P.    If $x < y$ then the value of the parentheses is equal to 1 mod p and hence still not a multiple of P.

Comment: @badjohn Now I get it. If you put that as an answer, I at least would upvote it.

Comment: My argument was still not quite right but I hope that the one below is.I don't have an idea for the non-integral case yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may, and do, assume that $ x $ is an integer upon multiplication by an appropriate power of $ P $ on both sides of the equality $ P^x + P^y = P^z $.

The crucial tool we will use is the field trace. Take a Galois extension $ L/\mathbf Q $ containing all of $ P^x, P^y, P^z $. Then, we have the following result:

**Lemma.** Let $ P^a \in L $. Then, $ \textrm{Tr}_{L/\mathbf Q}(P^a) = 0 $ if and only if $ a $ is an integer.

**Proof.** Let $ a = b/c $ in reduced form, with $ c > 1 $. The trace is some positive integer multiple of the sum of all $ \mathbf Q $-conjugates of $ P^a = P^{b/c} $, and these conjugates are the $ \zeta_c^k P^{b/c} $ for $ 0 \leq k \leq c - 1 $, where $ \zeta_c $ is a primitive $ c $th root of unity. It is trivial to check that these sum to $ 0 $. On the other hand, if $ c = 1 $, then this sum is just $ P^b $, thus nonzero.

Armed with this lemma, we cover four cases:

1. Neither $ y $ nor $ z $ are integers. In this case, taking field traces on both sides of the equality yields $ P^x = 0 $, which is absurd.
2. $ y $ is an integer, but $ z $ is not. This is a contradiction, since one side of the equality $ P^x + P^y = P^z $ is then irrational, whereas the other side is an integer.
3. $ z $ is an integer, but $ y $ is not. This gives a contradiction in view of the fact that $ P^x - P^z $, being an integer, is rational; whereas $ P^y $ is not.
4. Both $ y $ and $ z $ are integers. This case has been covered by another answer; and it's a simple comparison upon assuming wlog that $ x \leq y < z $. (This is the only case for which we need the condition $ P > 2 $.)

All four cases are ruled out, thus the equation has no solutions with $ x $ integral; thus it has no (rational) solutions at all.

Comment: Nice answer, though I don't think OP will understand it. Anyways, +1.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. To be honest, the answer itself is somewhat beyond the knowledge I have had. I am just an engineer who loves mathematics. I would wait for someone to further confirm the correctness of this answer, so sorry. [+1]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer: there are no positive integral solutions if $P > 2$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume $x \le y$ so $P^x$ is a common factor of the two terms in the left hand side.  Hence, 
$$P^x(1 + P^{y-x}) = P^z$$
If $x = y$ then the left hand side is $2P^x$ which is a multiple of $2$ and cannot be equal to $P^z$ if $P > 2$.

If $x < y$ then the left hand side is divisible by $(1 +  P^{y-x})$ which is one more than a multiple of $P$ and hence not a multiple of $P$.  The right hand side is only divisible by powers of $P$.

I think that I can the add the half positive integer case.  I still assume $P > 2 $ and I will retain $x$, $y$, $z$ as positive integers with $x < y$ but rewrite your equation as:

$$P^{x/2} + P^{y/2} = P^{z/2}$$

Square both sides:

$$P^x + 2P^{\frac{x+y}{2}} + P^y = P^z$$

Rearranging:

$$2P^{\frac{x+y}{2}} = P^z - P^x - P^y$$

The right hand side is an integer.

If $x + y$ is even then the left hand side is also an integer but the left is even and the right is odd so that is not possible.

If $x + y$ is odd then $\frac{x + y - 1}{2}$ is an integer.  So, the square root of $P$ must be rational which is not possible since P is a prime integer.

$$P^{1/2} = \frac{P^z - P^x - P^y}{2P^{\frac{x + y + 1}{2}}}$$

Further special cases may be possible in this style but will be messy.  Some form of induction on the lcm of the denominators of $x, y, z$ might be possible.

Comment: I didn't notice OP allows rational $x,y,z$ but still this answer covers the integer case in my opinion. [+1]

Comment: I just edited my answer to add the half integer case.

Comment: Thanks very much! For positive integers $x, y, z$, the inequality $P^x + P^y \neq P^z$ holds for $P > 2$, where $P$ is not necessarily to be a prime number. Your idea is great! Thanks again for your answer! [+1]

Answer (score 2):

@badjohn, the fact that $P^x + P^y = P^z$ has no solutions in integers is trivial isn't it? (how can odd number + odd number = odd number?)

Comment: Yes, of course, it could have been even easier.

Comment: Ask sku points out, it is trivial for P odd (whether prime or not).  An argument for all cases (prime or not, even or not) > 2 is also quite easy.  As ever, wlog, assume $x \le y$ and clearly $x \le z$ so $P^x$ is factor of all terms and can be divided out.  $$1 + P^{y-x} = P^{z-x}$$ So, we are looking for two different powers of P which differ by 1.  This is only possible for $2^0$ and $2^1$.  So, $P = 2$, $y = x$ and $z = x + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with no Galois theory.

Suppose wlog that $ x \leq y \lt z $ are (not necessarily positive) rationals solving the equation $P^x + P^y = P^z$ for some prime $P$.

Then divide by $P^x$ to obtain $1 + P^{y-x} = P^{z-x}$.

Now write $y - x = \frac{a}{d}$ and $z - x = \frac{b}{d}$ for some integers $a \geq 0, b \gt 0, d \gt 0$. Moreover, $b > a$.

Now $P^{\frac{1}{d}}$ is a common root of $X^d - P$ and $X^b - X^a - 1$. Since $X^d - P$ is irreducible (by Eisenstein's criterion), this implies that $X^d - P$ divides $X^b - X^a - 1$.

Thus $X^b - X^a - 1 = f(X)(X^d - P)$ for some polynomial $f(X)$ which can be assumed to be in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by Gauss' lemma. But, if $a > 0$ then the constant term on the RHS is a multiple of $P$, which contradicts the constant term of $-1$ on the LHS. Thus $a = 0$, and $P = 2$.

Translating back to our old variables, this means $x = y$ and we get $2^x + 2^x = 2^z$ with only solution $y = x, z = x + 1, P = 2$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear answer! [+1]

Comment: I had a conversation with Starfall on IRC (or someone claiming to be, but it doesn't matter), and after all we don't need Gauss' lemma to show that $f(X)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. You can just use polynomial division and since $X^d - P$ is monic, you can cancel successive powers with integer multiples of $X^i$ times $X^d - P$.